# calculate bmi with javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I am currently creating a program that can calculate bmi with javascript. I am not sure why but it is not working properly. I must be missing something but I am not sure what it is. If someone could help me I would really appreciate it. Thank you.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
   <!--    -->
<html>

   <head>
      <meta charset="UTF-8" />
      <title>Body Mass Index</title>
   </head>


   <BODY>
    <header><img src="bmi.jpeg" width="380" height="132" border="0" alt="bmi"></header>

<video controls="controls"
width="320px" height="260px">
<source src="bmi.mp4"/>

      <p>When it comes to weight loss, there's no lack of fad diets promising fast results. But such diets limit your nutritional intake, can be unhealthy, and tend to fail in the long run.</p>

      <p>The key to achieving and maintaining a healthy weight isn't about short-term dietary changes. It's about a lifestyle that includes healthy eating, regular physical activity, and balancing the number of calories you consume with the number of calories your body uses.</p>

      <p>BMI is a number calculated from a person's weight and height. BMI provides a reliable indicator of body fatness for most people and is used to screen for weight categories that may lead to health problems.</p>

      <p>The BMI ranges are based on the relationship between body weight and disease and death. 
      Overweight and obese individuals are at increased risk for many diseases and health conditions, including the following:</p>





You need a flash player to view this video.

</video>

      <ul>
        <li>Hypertension</li>
        <li>Dyslipidemia (for example, high LDL cholesterol, low HDL cholesterol, or high levels of triglycerides)</li>
        <li>Type 2 diabetes</li>
        <li>Coronary heart disease</li>
        <li>Stroke</li>
        <li>Gallbladder disease</li>
        <li>Osteoarthritis</li>
        <li>Sleep apnea and respiratory problems</li>
        <li>Some cancers (endometrial, breast, and colon)</li>
     </ul>

<script type="text/javascript">
function CalculateBMI(){
var inch=12;
var ft;
var bmi= Math.write(weight*703)/ (inch height)^2;

if(bmi<=19)
{"Underweight";
}
if else(19<bmi<=25)
{"Desirable";
} 
if else(25<bmi<=29)
{"Prone to health risks";
}
if else (29<bmi<=40)
{"obese"
}
else(40<bmi)
{"Extremely Obese"
} 
}
</script>
     <form name="bmi">


     <p> Weight:<p/></td>  <td><input type="text" id="weight" name="weight" size="25" />


<p>Height:</p> <input type="text" id="textbox" name="textbox" size="25" /><td><p>Ft.</p><input type="text" id="textbox" name="textbox" size="25" /> <p>In.</p>

<input type="submit" id="Calculate BMI" name="Calculate BMI" value="Calculate BMI" size="25" onclick="CalculateBMI()" />
 According to the Panel on 
Energy, Obesity, and Body Weigth Standards published by
American Journal of Clinical Nurttrition, your category is:
<input type="text" id="textbox" name="textbox" size="25" />


     </form>

   </BODY>

</html>
```

Comment: Sorry, but the code is full of errors. Start by [opening the browser console](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/8525/how-to-open-the-javascript-console-in-different-browsers) and working out the syntax errors first.

Answer (score 1):

I see a few things that are likely causing your issue. Lets start with this statement:

```
var bmi= Math.write(weight*703)/(inch height)^2;
```

You are not defining weight or height (you have to tell it to look in the textbox or send it to the function it does not automatically know you are referring to a textbox). I would expect something like

```
var weight = document.getElementById('weight').value;
```

There is no Symbol between height and weight, which is throwing a syntax error, you need to do something with these if they are going to be together (and do realize this is not adding the inches just calculating the feet in inches).

var bmi= (weight*703)/(inch*height)^2;

After that you are using if else - which is not valid in Javascript you would want to say:

```
else if (19<bmi<=25)
```

Lastly you are not returning a value nor specifying WHERE the value should go.

```
var results;
if (bmi<=19)
{
  results = "Underweight"
}

document.getElementById('results').value = results;
```

Try implementing some of these suggestions and see if that gets you on the right track.

Answer (score 0):

Your javascript had several systemic errors

for example `1<a<12` is not valid, it should be written `a>1 && a<12`

also, your `CalculateBMI` function had no idea what weight height in inches or height in feet where. You can include `JQuery` to make this easier but `document.getElementById` also works. To accomplish this I also gave meaningful names to your form variables.

You were not displaying the resulting string anywhere. Using `getElementById` you can also find the result element in your html and set its value to the result of the calculation.

If you don't want the page to refresh when you submit you have to set your form to receive a `false` value `onsubmit`.

Your math syntax for the bmi was off, I'm assuming it should be (703 * weight ) (height)^2 where height is in inches (after the foot and inch height variables have been combined).

The cleaned up Javascript should look like this. Note that this is probably not the best way to go about solving this problem.

**edit:** I think your BMI calculation was off as well. If the input weight and height are imperial (ie inch and lbs) then the inches should be multiplied by 0.025 to get meters and lbs should be multiplied by 0.45 to get kgs.

`bmi= (weight_e* 0.45) / (((12*heightf_e)+heighti_e) * 0.025)^2;`

```
function CalculateBMI(){
    // To avoid erros due to hoisting define all
    // of your vars at the top of your function    
    var ft,
    bmi,
    heighti_e, // height in inches
    heightf_e, // height in feat
    weight_e,
    bmi_e,  // the bmi element
    bmi;                 
    // Use getElementById to get a reference for the
    // elements you will be using in your function
    heighti_e=document.getElementById("heighti");
    heightf_e=document.getElementById("heightf");
    weight_e=document.getElementById("weight");
    bmi_e=document.getElementById("bmi");
    // Not all of these parenthesis are necessary but it
    // helps to clear up the order of operation and avoid
    // silly mistakes in long equations that are not
    // broken up into several lines
    bmi= (weight_e* 0.45) / (((12*heightf_e)+heighti_e) * 0.025)^2;
    //  set bmi to a string value
    if(bmi<=19)
    {
    bmi="Underweight";
    }
    else if(bmi>19 && bmi<=25)
    {
    bmi="Desirable";
    } 
    else if(bmi>25 && bmi<=29)
    {
    bmi="Prone to health risks";
    }
    else if (bmi>29 && bmi<=40)
    {
    bmi="obese";
    }
    else(bmi>40)
    {
    bmi="Extremely Obese";
    }
    bmi_e.value=bmi; // bmi_a is the reference to the
                     // element in your form with the
                     // bmi id
    return false; // make sure you return false to prevent
                  // page reload
}
```

I have not cleaned up your HTML form, but at least it now works. I have moved the submission action from the button to the form tag. I have also given the height weight and bmi inputs meaningful id names so we can reference them in the `CalculateBMI` function.

```
<form action="" name="bmi" onsubmit="return CalculateBMI()">
     <p> Weight:<p/></td>  <td><input type="text" id="weight" name="weight" size="25" />

  <p>Height:</p> <input type="text" id="heightf" name="textbox" size="25" /><td><p>Ft.</p><input type="text" id="heighti" name="textbox" size="25" /> <p>In.</p>

  <input type="submit" id="Calculate BMI" name="Calculate BMI" value="Calculate BMI" size="25" />
  According to the Panel on 
  Energy, Obesity, and Body Weigth Standards published by
  American Journal of Clinical Nurttrition, your category is:
  <input type="text" id="bmi" name="textbox" size="25" />
</form>
```

Comment: Thank you. This really helps a lot. It helps me understand javascript a lot better than I did but no matter the outcome it saids that I am extremely obese